# Unable to trace an element by attribute or text

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having trouble with clicking at an element of a menu which is written like this:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="tabs ctrlTabsProfile">
<li class="active" data-tab="tabDetail">User Details</li>
<li data-tab="tabEmail">Email</li>
<li data-tab="tabPass">Change password</li>
<li data-tab="tabAdress">Account Details</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried these:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account Details")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-tab=tabAdress")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[data-tab='tabAdress']")).click();
```

also tried listing the elements but got `null` only :

```
for(WebElement el : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tabs.ctrlTabsProfile"))) {

        try {
            assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Account Details[\\s\\S]*$"));
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("Not found: \"Account Details\".");
          }

    String s = el.getAttribute("data-tab");
    System.out.println(s);
    if(s.equals("tabAdress")) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[data-tab='tabAdress']")).click();
    }
   }
```

Solutions? Sugestions? Errors?

Comment: Are those 3 tabs always displayed or do you have to click on Men to display those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one, your xpath selector is incorrect.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("li[data-tab='tabAdress']")).click();
```

should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-tab='tabAdress']")).click();
```

edit:

And your css selector is incorrect as well.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-tab=tabAdress")).click();
```

should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-tab='tabAdress']")).click();
```

edit #2:

and:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account Details")).click();
```

will only work if the element is a link, which in this case it is not.

Comment: also, not sure what you were trying to accomplish with your code block, but I can tell by glancing at it and the html you pasted that it will not work.  You're trying to retrieve a data-tab attribute from the .ctrlTabsProfile object, but that object does not have that attribute.  And your findElements call will only ever return one element, since your selector is just selecting the parent of your list items.

Answer (score 1):

Aholt is right, `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tabs.ctrlTabsProfile"))` will return only `ul` elements. To access all `<li>`, you could try:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.tabs.ctrlTabsProfile li.active"))
```

Comment: yes, good point, I would probably not find that, thank you and have a nice day!